# Regex from `=>` until 1st `\n`

Tags: python, regex

Here's my string:

```
"5th => fifth\n6th => sixth\n7th => seventh\n8th => eighth\n9th => ninth\n10th => tenth\n11th => eleventh\n12th => twelfth\n"
```

It was read from a .txt file, and the output above is what it prints. The "\n" represents newline. In the text file, I would have:

```
5th => fifth
6th => sixth
```

I've tried `substitution_regex = re.compile(r"(?==>(.*?)\\)")`, which according to this [link](https://regex101.com/r/o8thNR/1) should work, but when I do
`substitution_regex.search(string)`, I get `None`.

Why is that?

Comment: There is nothing in your regex that would delimit the end by a newline. Are those newlines in the string or actual slashes followed by `n`?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo `.` does not match newline unless using `re.DOTALL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\` is attempting to match a literal `\` character

`\n` is simply not matched always unless you specify `re.DOTALL`

simply exclude the `\\` from your regex

you will also need to use a greedy regex

```
>>> substitution_regex = re.compile(r"=>(.*)")   
>>> substitution_regex.findall(s)                
[' fifth', ' sixth', ' seventh', ' eighth', ' ninth', ' tenth', ' eleventh', ' twelfth']
```

Comment: This gives me `('',)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these:

```
>\s(.*)
```

or

```
>\s(\w*)
```

Example:

```
import re 

s = "5th => fifth\n6th => sixth\n7th => seventh\n8th => eighth\n9th => ninth\n10th => tenth\n11th => eleventh\n12th => twelfth\n"
# substitution_regex = re.compile(r">\s(.*)")
substitution_regex = re.compile(r">\s(\w*)")
substitution_regex.findall(s)
```

Output:

```
['fifth',
 'sixth',
 'seventh',
 'eighth',
 'ninth',
 'tenth',
 'eleventh',
 'twelfth']
```

#### For your purpose:

Use this for finding keys:

```
(\w*)\s=
```

Code:

```
import re 

s = "5th => fifth\n6th => sixth\n7th => seventh\n8th => eighth\n9th => ninth\n10th => tenth\n11th => eleventh\n12th => twelfth\n"

# Extract keys in list : ['5th', '6th', ...]
keys_regex = re.compile(r"(\w*)\s=")
keys = keys_regex.findall(s)  

# Extract Values in list : ['fifth', 'sixth', ...]
values_regex = re.compile(r">\s(\w*)")
values = values_regex.findall(s) 
 
# Making a dictionary from keys and values
result = dict(zip(keys, values))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'5th': 'fifth', '6th': 'sixth', '7th': 'seventh', '8th': 'eighth', '9th': 'ninth', '10th': 'tenth', '11th': 'eleventh', '12th': 'twelfth'}
```